# SQL How to convert this to a SubQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Learning, be kind.*

I am trying to understand how this works and I have done several successful conversions, but this one I am stumped on.

How do I take this code and convert it to a subquery?  I'm a little lost.

```
SELECT o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver, COUNT(DISTINCT s.vehicleID) NoOfBusesUsed
FROM Operators AS o, Runs AS r, Schedules AS s JOIN Trips AS t
ON s.scheduleID = t.scheduleID 
WHERE r.BidDate BETWEEN '09/01/2004' AND '09/30/2004'
GROUP BY o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName
HAVING COUNT(s.vehicleID) > 1
```

Here is how my tables are setup.  If more info is needed, I can post.

```
CREATE TABLE Operators
    (
    SeniorityNumber     char(4)     NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT ck_Operators_Seniority 
            CHECK (SeniorityNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), 
    FirstName               varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
    LastName                varchar(35) NOT NULL, 
    HireDate                    smalldatetime
            CONSTRAINT ck_Operators_HireDate CHECK (HireDate <=Getdate())
    )

CREATE TABLE Trips
    (
    RouteNumber         varchar(4)      NOT NULL, 
    StartLocation           varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    StartTime               time                NOT NULL, 
    EndLocation         varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    EndTime                 time                NOT NULL,
    EffectiveDate           smalldatetime   NOT NULL
        CHECK (EffectiveDate >= cast('1/1/2000' as smalldatetime)),
    CONSTRAINT ck_Trips_StartEnd CHECK (EndTime > StartTime)
    )

CREATE TABLE Vehicles
    (
    Manufacturer            varchar(50)
        DEFAULT 'Gillig',
    Model                   varchar(50), 
    ModelYear               int
        DEFAULT DatePart(yyyy,GetDate())
        CHECK (ModelYear <= DatePart(yyyy,GetDate())),

    PurchaseDate            smalldatetime
    )

    GO
    ALTER TABLE operators
        ADD OperatorID int IDENTITY --Primary Key

    GO
    ALTER TABLE Operators
        ADD CONSTRAINT pkOperators Primary key (OperatorID)

    ALTER TABLE Vehicles
        ADD VehicleID   int IDENTITY Primary Key

    ALTER TABLE Trips
        ADD TripID      int IDENTITY Primary key
    GO

CREATE TABLE Runs
(
    RunID           int     IDENTITY        NOT NULL        Primary Key,
    OperatorID  int     NOT NULL        REFERENCES Operators,
    BidDate     date    NOT NULL        
        CONSTRAINT ckRunBidDate CHECK
        (biddate <= dateadd(mm,6,getdate())) --getdate() + 180
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Schedules
(
    ScheduleID  int     IDENTITY        Primary Key,
    RunID           int     NOT NULL,
    VehicleID       int     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Schedules_Runs FOREIGN KEY (RunID)
        REFERENCES Runs(RunID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Schedules_Vehicles FOREIGN KEY (VehicleID)
        REFERENCES Vehicles
)   

ALTER TABLE Trips
    ADD ScheduleID  int NULL REFERENCES Schedules
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use a query as a sub-query you can use `WITH` statement or a derived table like:

- `With`:

  ```
  ;WITH subQuery AS (
      /* Your query here */
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM subQuery
  ```
- Derived table

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
      /* your query here */
      ) As subQuery
  ```

---

I think you should use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver, 
    DT.cnt AS NoOfBusesUsed
FROM 
    Operators AS o
JOIN
    (SELECT
        r.OperatorID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT s.VehicleID) AS cnt
     FROM
        Schedules s
     JOIN
        Runs r ON s.RunID = r.RunID
    ) AS DT
    ON  DT.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
WHERE
    ISNULL(DT.cnt, 0) > 1
```